# Alloy results: what does vars mean? primary vars? clauses?

Tags: alloy

Below is a graphic showing a result that Alloy produced. I have drawn a box around three numbers. What do each of the numbers mean, please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Alloy tool translates your model into a *boolean expression*. This expression is in [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) form. CNF is a set of or clauses that are anded.

```
   cnf     ::= clause ( '∧' clause )*
   clause  ::=  '(' var ( '∨' var )* ')'
   var     ::=  '¬'? ID
```

SAT solvers can then find values for the variables identified by ID that make the whole expression true.

```
   (_1 ∨ _2)  ∧ (¬_1 ∨ _2 )
```

This is true when var _2 is true.

Alloy changes every constraint in your model to such an expression. I actually not sure about the difference between primary and other vars. I assume it has to do what part of the model is translated.